# Visual Studio 2010 compilation error

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Win XP and I'm having a strange problem.

If I try to build a project where the code fails:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#top').clone()).remove().html();
```

Visual Studio stops with an error which is normal.

Now if I comment out the line or even delete the line from the code Visual Studio still stops at the same exact line. It doesn't matter if I choose to clean the solution or rebuild it, it doesn't even help to restart Visual Studio. And I know the rest of the code is perfectly legit because before adding this line everything worked fine.

So in short: it seems like Visual Studio is holding on to the line I already removed! Anyone else have this same problem or knows how to fix this?

EDIT: Just to add more info.

The function I'm trying to call is inside a plugin that I wrote. I know the problem is not in connecting to the plugin because there are 2 other methods in the plugin that work fine.

The method code is:

```
$.fn.tristate = function (options)
{
    var defaults =
        {
            idSAll: ""
        };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function ()
    {

    }); // End of this.each
}; // End of tristate
```

And the call to the method is:

```
$("#multiTest").tristate();
```

Where "#multiTest" is a div.
And the error message is:

> "Microsoft JScript error: Object
>   doesn't support this property or
>   method"

It originates in the call to the method (used to originate in the faulty line of code) and goes down to

> "jQery.ready();" in jquery-1.4.2.js and from there to "fn.call( document, jQuery );"

EDIT 2: Restarting the computer didn't help, renaming the method didn't work either.

Comment: Try deleting several lines above and below...it's possible a weird character has slipped in there that the compiler doesn't like.

Comment: @Nick Craver I deleted everything from the method this line was in and no luck.

Comment: @Hjalti - Next step, what *is* the error?  Always, always, always post the error you get, it's there for a reason :)

Comment: @Nick Craver Hehe sorry, didn't think it was relevant but here it is: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method".
If I comment out the call to the method then there's no problem, but the strange thing is that the method is empty now, there's no code inside.

Comment: @Graham Clark Yes and clean but it did nothing

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem but I have no idea why it fixed the problem.

To fix the problem I copied one of the methods that worked, changed the name and deleted the contents. For some reason this worked.

Faulty method:

```
$.fn.tristate = function (options)
{
    var defaults =
        {
            idSAll: ""
        };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function ()
    {
        var $obj = $(this);

    });
};
```

Non-faulty method:

```
$.fn.tristate = function (options)
{
    var defaults =
        {
            idSAll: ""
        };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function ()
    {
        var $obj = $(this);

    });
};
```

As you can see there is no difference between them!

I even compared them with a program called DiffMerge and it found no differences! Still Visual Studio fails to build the first one but not the latter.

So if you get into a problem like the one I described in the question, try to copy a working method if you have one, if not maybe delete the file and start from scratch.